# flutter data table with the right element

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-layout

below there is a part where it is bold , i need to make the row to work with future build as specified below

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('  '),
    ),
    body: SizedBox(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Expanded(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: DataTable(
              columnSpacing: 38.0,
              columns: [
                DataColumn(label: Text('no')),
                DataColumn(label: Text('driver')),
                DataColumn(label: Text('Status')),
                DataColumn(label: Text('faultName')),
                DataColumn(label: Text('faultlocationname')),
                DataColumn(label: Text('cost')),
                DataColumn(label: Text('curr')),

              **],
              rows: List.generate(drivers.length, (index) {
                   FutureBuilder<List<MaintenanceDetailsByDriverNo>>(
                    future: futureMaintenanceDetailsByDriverNo,
                       builder: (context, snapshot) {
                             if (snapshot.hasData) {**
                                      child:[
                               DataCell(Container(width: 75, child: Text(
                                 '${snapshot.data![index].iD
                                     .toString()} ',
                                 textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                                 style: TextStyle(
                                     fontSize: 18.5),),)),
                                        DataCell(Container(width: 75, child: Text(
                                          '${snapshot.data![index].driverName
                                              .toString()} ',
                                          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 18.5),),)),
```

it returns red screen , how can i fix this ?anyone? any ideas?
below is the error text
Failed assertion: line 401 pos 15: '!rows.any((DataRow row) => row.cells.length != columns.length)': is not true.

Answer (score 0):

Try viewing output of row. Maybe cells in row are greater in number and that is what causing the error.

Comment: so i flipped the columns and rows now i have the error "Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget"

Comment: and that is what i changed :  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('  '),
        ),
        body: SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery
                .of(context)
                .size
                .width,
       child:Expanded(